# How to create an Object in an particular Database

Tags: database, zope

I have diffrent Databases with ZEO Sync.
Now i have to create a new Object like "Folder" in an particular Database.

But where in the manage Interface can i choose the Database i want to create the Object?

I'm using Zope2.10

My Mountpoints:

```
database 1 <-> /mymount/2009

database 2 <-> /mymount/2010

database 3 <-> /mymount/2011
```

so i have database 4 and want to create /mymount/2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a Mount Point in an Empty Zope with the folder/object Structure and copy it on the zodb and mount it at the zope you want.

That was the way i get it in without losing Data or create a Object in the wrong database